# how to sum up a list of timestamps by the speaker name v.2

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, datetime

i am working on a project
and i have extracted data from lists and have now 3 lists:

list 1 - a list of speaker names

```
['<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>']
```

list 2 - a list of the beginning of talk time stamps

```
['[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:27.610]']
```

list 3 - a list of the ending of talk time stamps

```
['[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.290]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:20.250]', '[00:01:33.850]', '[00:01:47.150]', '[00:01:49.370]', '[00:01:50.140]', '[00:02:01.350]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:20.150]', '[00:02:27.610]', '[00:02:39.040]']
```

what I need to do is whenever a single speaker talked many times (for example the first 5 elements of the list)
I need change the first ending segment [00:00:08.010] to [00:00:48.100] and get rid of all the entries in between (turn the 5 entries where there was a single talker to 1 entry)
and do this again for all speakers in the list.
if the speaker talked only once so it needs to stay the same.

i have another rule i need to follow which i dont know how to implement, 
if someone talked 5 times straight (like the example in the beginning )and there is a space of 
over 0.5 seconds between sentence no.4 and sentence n.5 
the result should be two inputs 
for example

```
['<M1>', '<M1>']
```

the first 0.00- 0.39 and the second 0.39 - 0.48 ( if there was this 0.5 seconds space)

can someone please help me and find a way of how to do this in python? 
thanks !

here is what I wrote so far:

```
newSpeakerOrder = []
newSpeakerBegin = []
newSpeakerEnd   = []

currentspeaker = None
for i in range(len(speakers)):
    if currentspeaker != speakers[i]:
        if currentspeaker != None:
            newSpeakerEnd.append(end[i - 1])
        newSpeakerOrder.append(speakers[i])
        newSpeakerBegin.append(start[i])
        currentspeaker = speakers[i]
newSpeakerEnd.append(end[-1])
```

but it does not look at the times and takes the first time of the speaker and the last time he talked without separating them in case there is a difference of 0.5 seconds between time segmeents

```
<M1> [00:00:00.000]     [00:00:39.980]
<M1> [00:00:40.600]     [00:00:48.100]
```

instead of

```
<M1> [00:00:00.000]    [00:00:48.100]
```

Comment: to clarify, if a speaker appears many times in a row, you don't want to simply sum up all his speech time but also split into blocks of speech time if there is a delay between two appearances?

Comment: exactly if there is a delay of over 0.5 seconds between appearances of the same speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with gaps of 0.5 seconds in a speakers segment, you need to convert the start and end times into `datetime` objects and compare the current `start` with the previous `end` value, and start a new segment when either the speaker changes or the gap is 0.5 seconds or more:

```
from datetime import datetime
import itertools

speakers = ['<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M1>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>', '<M2>']
start = ['[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:27.610]']
end = ['[00:00:08.010]', '[00:00:16.290]', '[00:00:26.210]', '[00:00:39.980]', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:00:56.770]', '[00:01:08.010]', '[00:01:20.250]', '[00:01:33.850]', '[00:01:47.150]', '[00:01:49.370]', '[00:01:50.140]', '[00:02:01.350]', '[00:02:16.010]', '[00:02:20.150]', '[00:02:27.610]', '[00:02:39.040]'] 

# convert times to datetime objects
startt = [datetime.strptime(t, '[%H:%M:%S.%f]') for t in start]
endt = [datetime.strptime(t, '[%H:%M:%S.%f]') for t in end]

newSpeakerOrder = []
newSpeakerBegin = []
newSpeakerEnd   = []

currentspeaker = None
currentend = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
for i in range(len(speakers)):
    if currentspeaker != speakers[i] or (startt[i] - currentend).total_seconds() >= 0.5: 
        if currentspeaker != None and currentend != None:
            newSpeakerEnd.append(end[i - 1])
        newSpeakerOrder.append(speakers[i])
        newSpeakerBegin.append(start[i])
    currentspeaker = speakers[i]
    currentend = endt[i]
newSpeakerEnd.append(end[-1])

print([(s, b, e) for s, b, e in zip(newSpeakerOrder, newSpeakerBegin, newSpeakerEnd)])
```

Output:

```
[
 ('<M1>', '[00:00:00.000]', '[00:00:16.290]'),
 ('<M1>', '[00:00:16.890]', '[00:00:48.100]'),
 ('<M2>', '[00:00:48.100]', '[00:01:20.250]'),
 ('<M1>', '[00:01:21.120]', '[00:01:33.850]'),
 ('<M1>', '[00:01:46.130]', '[00:01:47.150]'),
 ('<M2>', '[00:01:47.180]', '[00:01:49.370]'),
 ('<M1>', '[00:01:49.390]', '[00:01:50.140]'),
 ('<M2>', '[00:01:50.670]', '[00:02:01.350]'),
 ('<M2>', '[00:02:02.320]', '[00:02:20.150]'),
 ('<M2>', '[00:02:21.110]', '[00:02:39.040]')
]
```

Comment: thank you so much!! can you please explain to me what the datetime.fromtimestamp(0) does and why not make currentend a None like current speaker?

Comment: @MichaelBenHaym `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` creates a `datetime` which is the unix epoch i.e. `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. You could use `None` for `currentend` but because of the need to subtract it from another `datetime` (`startt[i]`), I thought it was safer for future versions of Python to make it of the same type. As long as your earliest start time is 5 seconds after midnight on 1970-01-01 you won't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Given these containers and the following assumptions:

- List 1 is always in order
- Lists 1, 2 & 3 are always equal in length
- Lists 1, 2 & 3 are vertically relatable

Then you can do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

speaker_times = {}

for speaker, timestamps in groupby(enumerate(list_1), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    start = timestamps[0][0]  # start time recorded
    end = timestamps[-1][0]  # end time recorded
    speaker_times[speaker] = [list_2[start], list_3[end]]
```

This condenses down your lists into a dictionary by `<M#>` in the form:

`<M#>: [start_time, end_time]`

The second part of your problem is confusing, can you edit your original post to further clarify what you mean by a 0.5 second gap? You show `00.00.00 - 00.00.39` and `00.00.39 - 00.00.48`, but neither one of those are a `00.00.05` gap (assuming your format is `hh.mm.ss`).

Comment: yes, these ones do not have this gap but ive been told that future lists i will get will have this gap and because of that i  need to add this option for future entries

Comment: @MichaelBenHaym That still does not make sense, because you said "... is a space of over 0.5 seconds..." and many of the timestamps in `list_3` have a gap >0.5 seconds. So again I urge you to update your original post with an example of what you're asking.

Comment: originally my scripts sums it up to 1 entry of M1 with seconds 0.00.00- 0.00.48 but i want the output to be two seprate entries of M1 with one  where the start, end will be 00.00.00 - 00.00.39 and the second  00.00.39 - 00.00.48 if there is a difference of 0.5 seconds between the end time of the first one and start time of the second one AKA a 0.5 seconds gap

Comment: @MichaelBenHaym So there will be a maximum of 2 entries for `<M1>`? That is to say, if a speaker has multiple occurrences and if the difference between the second to last and last end time stamp is 0.5 seconds, then the result should be `[('<M1>', start_time to second_to_last_end_time), ('<M1>', second_to_last_end_time to end_time)]`? The reason your question is confusing is because youre binning `00.00.00` to `00.00.39` on a 0.5 second gap; but if you only want a maximum of 2 entries, then its doable.

Comment: i tried to edit and add an example, there shouldnt be a max of entries but in case that there is a difference of over 0.5 seconds between the end of segement1 and start of segement2 it needs to be seperated and not joined into one entry

Comment: @MichaelBenHaym There is still confusion. For example, why would you have this entry `<M1> [00.00.00] [00:00:16.290]`? Its segment 1 and segment 2 and has a >= 0.5 second gap. Youre not clearly stating why you binned the first 4 segments of `<M1>` together.

Comment: because the comparisons need to be between the 1 ending segment and the next beginning segement, if there isnt a gap of over 0.5 seconds then a couple of appearences of the same speaker needs to be summed into one entry